# Clearing Site Data Breaks Mapping - IndexedDB isn't handling a closed connection

Tags: here-api

Repro Steps:

1. Load a Map
2. In Chrome dev tools, visit the Application tab and click "Clear site data"
3. Return to your map and scroll or pan
4. Exception thrown and map becomes unresponsive to input

   Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase'...

Looks like the team isn't catching errors in IndexedDB. As a consumer of the library, we can't reliably catch this error either because JavaScript global error handlers don't get error information for scripts loaded from another domain.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use Maps API for JavaScript 3.1 instead of 3.0. The new version 3.1 doesn't have this flaw.
See please on [Migration to 3.1](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/migration.html) and [Examples](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js)

Comment: Sweet! Only one year after I asked. Good SLA ;)